# Problem: confidence intervals for excess absolute risk (EAR)

Tags: r, confidence-interval

Can anyone help me to get confidence intervals for excess absolute risk (EAR) with the following function in R?

```
library(popEpi)
data(popmort)
data(sire)
c <- lexpand( sire, status = status, birth = bi_date, exit = ex_date, entry = dg_date,
              breaks = list(per = 1950:2013, age = 1:100, fot = c(0,10,20,Inf)),
              aggre = list(fot, agegroup = age, year = per, sex) )
## SMR due other causes: status = 2
sr <- sir( coh.data = c, coh.obs = 'from0to2', coh.pyrs = 'pyrs',
           ref.data = popmort, ref.rate = 'haz',
           adjust = c('agegroup', 'year', 'sex'), print = 'fot',
           EAR = T)

sr
```

I tried to find other functions and solutions, but couldn't find any.